How do i establish a connection with twillio (THROUGH ZAPIER) for whatsapp messaging with API Request (Beta)?
im trying to figure out how i can establish an funnelish abandoned checkout flow with whatsapp messaging (Towards the customer). Does anyone have experience with setting up the API Request (Beta) in zapier and with twillio?
Would really appreciate some help! Willing to pay if it leads to a solid solution!
making an abandonment flow with whatsapp messages for customers that dont complete their purchase on my funnelish checkout.
trying to make a connection from funnelish to zapier to twillio.
Any help would be appreciated!
